# Question about jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

i want to select all h1 tags except myclass with jQuery. For example i want select < h1> but i don't want to select < h1 class="myclass">

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) or [`not` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("h1:not(.myclass)")
$("h1").not(".myclass")
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("h1:not('.myclass')")
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: +1 for link to API reference.  Insert "Give a man a fish/teach a man to fish" to analogy here.